# What is the name of the count of leading bits encoding technique used by UTF-8?

Tags: algorithm, encoding, utf-8

UTF-8 uses an encoding where the number of leading one bits of the first byte is the count of the number of bytes used by the symbol (except for single byte characters):

```
0xxxxxxx - 1 byte sequence
110xxxxx - 2 byte sequence
1110xxxx - 3 byte sequence
11110xxx - 4 byte sequence
...
```

Ignoring the single byte case, are there similar/prior uses of this encoding technique? Does it have a name?

Comment: Well, it's not so complicated as to warrant a name in my opinion. It's a simple bit string with a unary length field.

Comment: [Prefix-free binary codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code), if you are looking for prior uses look at the [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) algorithm, it was invented in 1951.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach using continuation bits is used for [variable-length integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_length_unsigned_integer).

[This patent application](http://www.freshpatents.com/-dt20100408ptan20100085223.php) discusses a number of approaches, including these two (presumably before offering a better alternative).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), the name used seems to be "continuation bytes".